# Using 'react-day-picker' DatePickerInput within a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-day-picker

I am trying to use a `DatePickerInput` component within a bootstrap modal.

I am expecting a similar effect to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rpMU.png), as demonstrated on the official website.

However, inside the bootstrap modal, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0PhJ.png).

I suppose that this is because the library tries to display the overlay at a certain z-index not knowing that the input itself is already in an elevated component.

How should I solve this problem?
Thank you so much!

Comment: plz share your code

Comment: did you put react-day-picker/lib/style.css in your html? 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker/lib/style.css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mrTurkay's comment solved my problem, I did not import the CSS file provided by the library.
Adding

```
`import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';`
```

solved this.